# Does Cognito a good option for developing multiplayers games?

Tags: android, multiplayer, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implementing a multiplayer android game and need a way to share game states and board among multiplayers. I am thinking about using AWS Cognito to share these data. But it seems that Cognito is used for a single user to shares its data among multiple devices. I am not sure if Cognito could meet my requirement -- share data among multiple players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cognito does not allow you to share data between players. Each Cognito Identity (ie: each player in your game) can only access its own data. This data is accessible across devices for a single user, but not from one user to another.

Comment: If you wish to see this feature, please make a feature request in Cognito forums. This will help us in prioritizing features in our development plans.

Comment: Why not simply use Amazon DynamoDB as your backend for this?

Comment: DynamoDB can be a good choice, and you can use Cognito to get credentials to access it directly from your app.